# Is it possible to break up an element itself before another join?

Tags: linq, linq-to-xml

I have got two xml documents, simplified as

```
  <NumSetA>
    <num Operation="+/-">1</num>
    <num Operation="+">3</num>
    <num Operation="+/*">4</num>
  </NumSetA>

  <NumSetB>
    <num>2</num>
    <num>9</num>
  </NumSetB>
```

I want to join NumSetA with NumSetB with the possible operations stated in the Operation tag, ie.
1+2, 1-2, 1+9, 1-9, 3+2, 3+9, 4+2, 4+9, 4*2, 4*9
by using string.split('/')

What I want to do is

```
var CrossJoin = SetA.Elements("num").join(this.attribute("Operation").value.split('/'), 
                                          .join(SetB.Elements("num"))
```

Sorry for being inventive. Hope you understand what I am saying.
How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty easy to do with the query syntax:

```
var crossJoin =
  from numA in SetA.Elements("num")
  from op in numA.Attribute("Operation").value.split('/')
  from numB in SetB.Elements("num")
  select new {
    a = numA.value,
    op,
    b = numB.value
  };
```

Comment: So this style is called query syntax. what about the function style? How do you call them. Are they equally powerful or some functions can only be achieved by one, but not another?

Comment: The other style is called 'method syntax'. There are somethings that can only be done in method syntax (for example: `.First()`) and there are somethings that are much easier to do in query syntax (for example: `let x = y`). That said, determing which is "better" to use is often up to preference.